# how to pass variable from view to route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

How to pass a variable from view to route in Laravel?

Here's the code at my `route.php`:

```
Route::get('/{id}/{id1}', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

And at `welcome.blade.php`:

```
< a href="{{URL::route('/{4}/{5}')}}">test</a>
```

I want to build a link referencing the route above.

Comment: Try passing an array:  `URL::route('route.name', ['id'=> 1, 'id2' => 2])`. Do a `dd(Request::all())` on the controller to check if the params are there.

Answer (score 7):

A good approach to do it would be to name your route and then reference it by name, passing the parameters needed. Here is how:
At `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/{id}/{id1}', ['as' => 'welcome_index', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index']);
```

And at your view, you can do this:

```
<a href="{{ route('welcome_index', [4, 5]) }}">test</a>
```

Notice that the first parameter represent the route name and the second, the parameters for your URL. You can read more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers#urls).

The advantages of naming a route is that you can change your route path later and your URL will still work with the code above.

Comment: Also, consider the way the route is applied in forms:  `Form::open(['route' => 'my-route', [4, 6]])`