# Laravel - How to pass variables from view to controller with form

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm building a request system with Laravel 7. In the index page, there is a form for user to fill in and a submit button. If the button is clicked, the data in the form will be sent to the supervisor via email. The email which the supervisor receives, all user input data will be listed along with a "Approve" button and a "Reject" button. If the "Approve" button is clicked, the user input data will be stored in the database. All user input data is stored in `$data` and can be accessed in email template view. So, in the email template, how do I pass the user input data and `Auth::user()->id` to the controller so that the storing process will start?
I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381836/how-to-pass-variable-from-view-to-route-in-laravel) and it looks useful to me, but it is using `<a>` to do the redirection to trigger the controller. Is it possible to pass the blade variables from the `<form>` in the email template view to the controller, so that I can use `<button>`?

***Update:***
index.blade.php:

```
<form action="/sendSupervisor" method="post">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">

  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('/sendSupervisor', 'CatViewController@sendSupervisor')->middleware('auth')->middleware('verified');
```

CatViewController.php:

```
// one of the methods
public function sendSupervisor()
    {
        $data = request();
        Mail::to('supervisor@abc.com')->send(new ApprovalMail($data));

        return redirect('/');
    }
```

approval.blade.php:

```
<!-- Email Template -->
User Input: {{ $data->name }}

<form action="/approve">
    <button>Approve</button>
</form>

<form action="/reject">
    <button>Reject</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you provide code snippet

Comment: @YomnaHesham Hi. The code snippet is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach:

It's better to save the user request once he post it with a column flag called "status" that holds either ("Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"), and then send an email to the supervisor

**index.blade**

```
<form action="/sendRequest" method="post">
     <input type="text">
     <input type="text">

     <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/sendRequest', 'MyController@sendRequest)
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function sendRequest(Request $request){
       // UserRequest table should has column 'status' with default value 'Pending'
       $userRequest = UserRequest::create($request->all());
       Mail::to('supervisor@abc.com')->send(new ApprovalMail($userRequest));

       return redirect('/');
}
```

The email template should only notify the supervisor to take an action with the request, with a button 'Take action' that opens a page in the browser for him to take the action.

**email-template.blade**

```
<!-- User data displayed for example in a table --> 
<a href={{ route('takeAction', $userRequest->id) }}>
   <button> Take Action <button>
</a>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/take-action/{requestId}', 'SupervisorController@takeAction')
     ->name('taleAction');
```

**SupervisorController.php**

```
public function takeAction($requestId){
       $userRequest = UserRequest::find($requestId);
       return view('take-action', [$userRequest]);
}
```

**take-action.blade**

```
<-- User data displayed for example in a table --> 
<form method='POST' action={{ route('takeActionPost', $userRequest->id) }}>
      @csrf
      <input type='hidden' name='action' value='Approved'>
      <button type='submit'>Approve</button>
</form>

<form method='POST' action={{ route('takeActionPost', $userRequest->id) }}>
      @csrf
      <input type='hidden' name='action' value='Rejected'>
      <button type='submit'>Rejected</button>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/take-action/{requestId}', 'SupervisorController@takeActionPost')
     ->name('takaActionPost');
```

**SupervisorController.php**

```
public function takeActionPost(Request $request, $requestId){
       $userRequest = UserRequest::find($requestId);
       $userRequest->update(['status', $request->action]);
}
```

***Of course the names I'm using here are very bad, I just want to explain my idea***

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So your approach is basically using additional table to save all the user request and access the table to get those user input in controller. But there are actually tens of different kinds of user input form. In the index page, there is a drop down list for user to choose and show corresponding input form, while the irrelevant will be hidden. That means, the additional table must be very large to store every single kind of input form even every time only 1 kind of all is useful. Is there a way not to use additional table?

Comment: You are saying in the question that (If the "Approve" button is clicked, the user input data will be stored in the database) .. So, you already has a table for the user data. What I say is to store this data once the user submits them not when the supervisor approve them. I didn't say make an additional table, I say add additional column to the existing table to hold the 'status'

Comment: @keanehui "That means, the additional table must be very large to store every single kind of input form" this is not true, if it is temporary data store it in a text or medium text field as json, then handle it like it was a request when you need it.

Comment: @KurtFriars I have all the user input from the form in `$data = request();`. Do you mean that I can save `$data` in one single cell in a table, and when I need any `input` I just need to get it back from the cell and use `$data->` to access a specific input box? Then what should be in the migration file, `$table->string('user_input');`, like this?

Answer (score 3):

An email is not a browser, and in almost every case a `<form>` tag will have no effect. You cannot retrieve user input from an email, however in your case if you have two buttons in the email, and that email is being sent to a user that exists in your system, AND the input you are receiving is 'accept' or 'reject' based on which button they click, this is doable.

You can have two routes that are publicly accessible and build two "buttons" with hrefs that will carry out those actions. Like:

```
Route::get('email/accept/{user_id}', 'EmailController@accept');
Route::get('email/reject/{user_id}', 'EmailController@reject');
```

Then link to those routes in your email temple like:

```
<a href="{{ action('EmailController@accept', ['user_id' => $user->id ]) }}">Accept</a>
<a href="{{ action('EmailController@reject', ['user_id' => $user->id ]) }}">Reject</a>
```

Then in that controller, you can resolve the user based on id in those methods, and you can carry out any logic you would like.

A note of caution: since these links need to be publicly accessible, using id's is not ideal. You should generate some sort of token to resolve the user.

Comment: and how the data will be saved in the database ?

Comment: Hi. The solution partially works for me, I can trigger corresponding method in mail controller now. However, how do I get the `$data` in the controller? I try to add this in the action function array: `\`data\` => $data`, but this doesn't work

Comment: @keanehui unfortunately, as I stated above, you cannot get any data from the user, from an email. This is true for a multitude of security reasons. You CAN NOT get user input from an email (in almost every case). The best you can do is create a set of secure links they can click on that are associated with actions, or directs them to a page you can receive further user input from.

Comment: @keanehui If you are talking about receiving $data from the form that initiates sending the email, then you should store the $data from the request in a table in the controller that handles that request, and associate it to the user if they accept, and delete it if they reject.

Answer (score 1):

Add hidden input fields in the form whose values are the user data. But I think there is a better design for your system that I'll explain in a separate answer.